# How to setup SparkJava CDI with DeltaSpike and Weld

Tags: java, cdi, weld, spark-java, deltaspike

So I've started setting up a simple SparkJava application from scratch with the basic goal of comparing it to a mirrored SpringBoot (with SpringData) application which I've already built. However I've been struggling with DeltaSpike (which is the alternative to SpringData chosen) setup as that adds a layer of CDI complexity which I didn't have to handle within SpringBoot.

Long story short after trying out some (probably wrong) approaches: now I'm stuck at enabling Weld (CDI) in the SparkJava Jetty container. I've taken a look on how to enable [Weld for Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-weld.html) but that only got me more confused - and I'm not even sure that it's supposed to work.

What I'm getting now is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/weld/events/WeldEvent`.

Since there are many files it's better to just share my github repo: https://github.com/vitorbmiranda/taskapp-sparkjava. Don't mind unused code and stuff like that as it's still a WIP.

A final disclaimer: apart from that error itself I feel like I may be completely missing something or my approach with SparkJava/CDI/DeltaSpike could be completely off, or my Maven dependencies could not make any sense, so any directions on that would also be appreciated. Cheers.

---

**Update Sep 2nd:** did a fresh setup on a [new repo](https://github.com/vitorbmiranda/cdi-test). Managed to [customize](http://blog.pythonaro.com/2019/02/how-to-customise-jetty-embedded-in.html) the Spark embedded Jetty handler and added the [Weld Listener](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-weld.html) to it.

This is how I've added the listeners:

```
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.BeanManagerResourceBindingListener;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener;
...
JettyHandler handler = new JettyHandler(matcherFilter);
...
handler.addEventListener(new BeanManagerResourceBindingListener());
handler.addEventListener(new Listener());
```

This is from the startup log (using TRACE level within `logback.xml`)

`5:46:50.427 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler1530180168==dftMaxIdleSec=-1 added {org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.BeanManagerResourceBindingListener@49483272,UNMANAGED}
15:46:50.432 [Thread-0] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.ContainerLifeCycle - spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler1530180168==dftMaxIdleSec=-1 added {org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener@62383f62,UNMANAGED}`

No "Weld" references after that. If I try to use any `@Inject`ed bean it won't work as expected (since logs didn't give me anything related to Bean/classpath lookup):

```
public class TestController {

  @Inject
  TestService testService;

  public static String getTest(Request request, Response response) {
    // NPE here
    testService.test();
    return value;
  }

}
```

```
@Default
public class TestService {

  public String test() {
    return "123";
  }

}
```

My `pom.xml` looks like:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-spi</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.SP1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The `META-INF/beans.xml` (which I would think it's not necessary, anyway) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
  bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working on that.